# Prolog: Multiplication(X,Y)

Tags: prolog

double(X, Y) :-
X is Y/2, Y is X*2.

I'm trying to execute this but its given error always

Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
In:
[2] 4 is _1604/2
[1] double(4,_1662) at  line 2

how can I get double of two variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to make a bidirectional procedure, where at least one of the parameters is instantiated.
You may use [*CLP(fd)*](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html) like this:

```
double(X, Y):- Y #= X*2.
```

Note this will only work with integer values, so for example

```
?- double(2, Y).
Y = 4.

?- double(X, 4).
X = 2.
```

but

```
?- double(2.5, Y).
ERROR: Domain error: `clpfd_expression' expected, found `2.5'
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [14] throw(error(domain_error(clpfd_expression,2.5),_2162))
ERROR:   [11] clpfd:parse_clpfd(2.5*2,_2200) at c:/swi/swi8/library/clp/clpfd.pl:7359
ERROR:    [9] clpfd:clpfd_equal(_2236,2.5*2) at c:/swi/swi8/library/clp/clpfd.pl:2795
ERROR:    [7] <user>
ERROR: 
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
?- double(X, 5).
false.
```

or if you want to use `is/2` then you should make sure that the right hand side of `is/2` is bound to an number, for example like this:

```
double(X, Y) :-
    (   number(X)
    ->  Y is X*2
    ;   number(Y)
    ->  X is Y/2
    ).
```

The procedure using CLP(fd) is clearly more powerful as it does not require the right hand arithmetic expression to be instantiated prior to issue the constraint, and thus allows queries like `double(X,Y)` to succeed (giving the remaining constraints upon querying).

You may also try [*CLP(r)*](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpqr) which works over reals:

```
:- use_module(library(clpr)).
double(X, Y):- { Y=X*2 }.
```

sample runs:

```
?- double(2, Y).
Y = 4.

?- double(X, 4).
X = 2.

?- double(2.5, Y).
Y = 5.0.

?- double(X, 5).
X = 2.5.
```

Comment: `double(X, X).` fails. How's that? I expected it to have one solution!

Comment: @false: added a link to CLP(fd) docs in SWI and some (small) comment on it over why it would be preferrable over using `is/2`

Comment: @false: in the second solution, double(X,X) fails, because number/1 fails if its argument is not instantiated, thus it does not serve as a generator.